# How do I build functionality to measure dimensions of a human foot?

Tags: 3d, arkit, arcore, dimensions

I am exploring AR and AI libraries around dimensions and measurement of the human foot.

While exploring, I come across the following article.
https://news.nike.com/news/nike-fit-digital-foot-measurement-tool

However, this article is more than a year old and I cannot see that functionality in the Nike app itself (checked Android and iPhone). I am intrigued because the precision required for shoes is in millimetres whereas the AR libraries and sensors in the mobile are not precise enough to support such functionality.

Does anyone have experience of using similar technology and which libraries they would have used to create such app? I have already explored ARKit and ARCore libraries however, they are not precise enough.

I am sure it will be a combination of AR, AI and ML. But that is a too wide area to explore.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out this post: https://ai.googleblog.com/2020/03/real-time-3d-object-detection-on-mobile.html

Also you can use the same method as Nike to take a picture of the feet (standing by the wall) and you can use ARCore Depth API to estimate the distance to the floor and then you can calculate the approximate size of a feet.
You can also use ARCore and draw a plane with different sizes on the floor and a person can compare.

Comment: Thank you Mulan - this answer is really helpful. Apologies for the delay.